# Url para remover itens do carrinho magento 1.9 ? Meu codigo não funciona

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

I'm trying to remove an item from the cart by adding a link to a href and it currently looks like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/delete', array('id' => $product->getId())) ?>">Button</a>
```

The problem is that when I click to remove it just redirects to home, and says it can't remove the item. How can I remove the item from the cart?

Answer (score 0):

you can remove an item from the Magento cart by item id:

```
$cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');

$cartItemId = 32;  //REPLACE YOUR ORIGNAL CART ITEM ID HERE

$cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($cartItemId)->save();
```